# Overriding set data method throws error

Tags: actionscript-3, overriding

I want to change the itemRenderer based on the value provided by dataProvider.
But overriding set data method gives error.

```
public class DataGridTypeRenderer extends DataGridColumn
    {

        private var _data:DataGridColumn;

        public function DataGridTypeRenderer()
        {
            super();
        }

        override public function set data(value:Object):void {
            // GIVED THE ERROR "Method marked override must override another method"
    }
```

Comment: It would help to tag your question with the language or technology you use.

Answer (score 0):

`DataGridColumn` is not an ItemRenderer and does not have a `data` property. You probably want to override `DataGridItemRenderer` instead.